# I want to fine 6th prime number. why execution is stuck after 3?

Tags: python-3.x, primes

Q:
By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.
What is the 10001st prime number?

My code is:

```
def is_prime(num):
    if all(num % i != 0 for i in range(2, num)):
        return True
    else:
        return False


def find_nth_prime(nth):
    lst_prime = []
    num = 2
    while len(lst_prime) < nth:
        if is_prime(num):
            lst_prime.append(num)
            print(len(lst_prime), ":", lst_prime[-1])
            num += 1
```

When I try to run `find_nth_prime(6)` it get stuck after finding "3" as prime. What am I missing here?

Comment: What happens inside the `while` loop when `is_prime` returns `False`? If you can't see it try using a step-by-step debugger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if statement inside while loop it keeps repeating at `n=4` since `n +=1` never happens as 4 is not a prime. Therefore take it out of the if statement.

Try using https://pythontutor.com/. It helps you visualize your code

```py
def find_nth_prime(nth):
    lst_prime = []
    num = 2
    while len(lst_prime) < nth:
        if is_prime(num):
            lst_prime.append(num)
            print(len(lst_prime), ":", lst_prime[-1])
        num += 1
```

Also you can do some improvments to your `is_prime` function. In that you don't have to take the whole range `(2, num)`. It is enough to take the range 2 to square root of num. `(2,int(num**0.5)+1)` or use `sqrt` from python's `math` library

Comment: Thanks, it works. But why when I drop ```else:``` after the ```if:``` the code skips "3" at the prime number list?

Comment: I write num += 1. what is the difference between 
```
def find_nth_prime(nth):
    lst_prime = []
    num = 2
    while len(lst_prime) < nth:
        if is_prime(num):
            lst_prime.append(num)
            print(len(lst_prime), ":", lst_prime[-1])
            num += 1
        **else:**
            **num += 1**
```
and what @cmgchess wrote in his solution?

Comment: @xRay with an else also you can do it but you will have to write `num += 1` inside both if and else part. i just ommited the else part and wrote n+=1 outside since nothing else is happening in else part

Comment: But why when you omitted the **else** statement and just entered the ```num += 1``` below the **if** the code skips the prime number 3?

Comment: did you do something like this https://replit.com/@cmgchess/KindFluffyTraining#main.py

Comment: **this is what I did:** https://codeshare.io/MNwd9O

Comment: in your version 2 it does num+=1 twice if the number is prime. thats why it skipped 3 after 2

Comment: Why? @cmhchess .

Comment: lets say n=2 it is a prime. then it appends to list and does n+=1. now n is 3. then it goes out of the `if` and finds another n+=1 then n becomes 4. so 3 is skipped. if you want to avoid the n+=1 outside the if wrap that in an else